# How to recognize Named Entity from a python list using Stanford NERTagger

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am a beginner in NLP and first time using StanfordNERTagger. For learning purpose I am playing with Stanford NERTagger. I have a python list of country name

```
['France', 'India', 'Bangladesh', 'England', 'Germany', 'Brazil', 'Egypt', 'Bhutan', 'Srilanka']
```

I want to get 'location' entity which belongs to  NERTagger but i am getting the 'Organization'  Entity

[('France', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('India', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Bangladesh', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('England', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Germany', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Brazil', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Egypt', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Bhutan', 'ORGANIZATION'),
 ('Srilanka', 'ORGANIZATION')]

May be i am missing something here

Comment: It's very difficult for an NER tagger to work with single words since the tagging is context-dependent. If you give it full sentences containing a country name, I would expect it to work much better.

Comment: you are asking for entities in a list of counties. NER tags entities on tokenized sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Firs you need to install  Stanford NER on your comp. Depending of OS, both procedures how to [configure Stanford ner tagger](https://blog.manash.me/configuring-stanford-parser-and-stanford-ner-tagger-with-nltk-in-python-on-windows-f685483c374a)

Now take a look at this sample code

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize.toktok import ToktokTokenizer
from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
stanford_classifier = os.environ.get('STANFORD_MODELS').split(':')[0]
stanford_ner_path = os.environ.get('CLASSPATH').split(':')[0]
st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path, encoding='utf-8')
```

Check st

```
<nltk.tag.stanford.StanfordNERTagger at 0x7f897c44e6d8>
```

My sentance

```
sentence = u'France is the biggest county in EU'
words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
st.tag(words)
```

Result

```
[('France', 'LOCATION'),
 ('is', 'O'),
 ('the', 'O'),
 ('biggest', 'O'),
 ('county', 'O'),
 ('in', 'O'),
 ('EU', 'LOCATION')]
```